# Install MongoDB and Tomcat using Dockerfile

Tags: python, mongodb, tomcat, docker

I was using the `Dockerfile` mentioned below to install packages of `python`, `mongodb` and `tomcaton` Centos6.

```
FROM centos:centos6
RUN yum install -y centos-release-scl && \
    yum install python27 &&
    echo -e "[mongodb-org-3.2]\nname=MongoDB Repository\nbaseurl==https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/\ngpgcheck=1\nenabled=1\ngpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc" > /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo && \
    yum install -y mongodb-org && \
    yum install -y tomcat6
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I was getting the error below

Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:

```
yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx-2016-12-16-05-51EmkBfY.yumtx
```

The command

```
/bin/sh -c yum install -y centos-release-scl &&     yum install python27 &&     echo -e "[mongodb-org-3.2]\nname=MongoDB Repository\nbaseurl==https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/\ngpgcheck=1\nenabled=1\ngpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc" > /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo &&     yum install -y mongodb-org &&     yum install -y tomcat6
```

`returned a non-zero code: 1`

Not sure what would be the possible problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos:centos6
RUN yum install -y centos-release-scl && \
    yum install -y python27 && \
    echo -e "[mongodb-org-3.2]\nname=MongoDB Repository\nbaseurl==https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/\ngpgcheck=1\nenabled=1\ngpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc" > /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org.repo && \
    yum install -y mongodb-org && \
    yum install -y tomcat6
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

You were missing `-y` before `python27` and `\` after `python27 &&`.